# AWS Elastic Load Balancer SSL support for specific endpoints

Tags: apache, http, ssl, https, amazon-elb

I would like to use HTTP for accessing some particular web pages, and HTTPS for some. I am using PHP over apache. I know that there is provision to support HTTP on some directory and HTTPS on other using apache configurations. Since I want to scale, I would want to have a load balancer beneath which many EC2 instances with apache+php will run.

I have read that ELB can be configured such that SSL/TLS connections from client close on it, and from there, HTTP connections follow to EC2. My question is pretty straight forward, is there any configuration possible on ELB similar to one on apache, where we could specify which web pages could be accessed over HTTP, and which over HTTPS? I believe that when ELB is configured such that SSL connection closes on it, then configuring apache to accept HTTP on some web pages and HTTPS on other doesn't make sense, as all the traffic on apache would be HTTP, hence, in such a scenario, it would be necessary to have an equivalent configuration on ELB. Is that the case? How are such requirements handled when ELB is configured to allow SSL such that SSL connections close on it? May be I am missing something very basic, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The ELB does not have a feature to support what you want to do. But as you describe you can use Apache mode_rewrite to rewrite the URLs that you want to HTTPS or vise versa and you need to setup your ELB to allow both HTTP and HTTPS for that. Regardless, SSL will be terminated at ELB and none SSL Traffic will pass through.